# how to fix cross site scripting vulnerability with Document.getelementbyid

Tags: visualforce, javascript, developer

I need to fix below code that came in cross site scripting vulnerability in App Scan.

There is no User Input, just displaying SSO error msg based on some condition.

Is below code really vulnerable?

If Yes how can I fix it?

Below code is written in a VF Page

```
<div> <p id="message" /> </div>

var messageBox = document.getElementById("message");

    if ("{!$CurrentPage.parameters.ErrorDetails}".indexOf("County") > 0) {



      messageBox.innerHTML = "{!$Label.ErrorMsg1}";

 }

    else {

      messageBox.innerHTML = "{!$Label.Single_Signon_Error}";

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code is vulnerable to attack. The `ErrorDetails` parameter is under the user's control (or the control of the entity that linked the user to this page), and you are merging it into your page's JavaScript without correctly escaping it. Therefore the statement

> There is no User Input

is incorrect.

This is a variety of Reflected XSS attack. You must escape this data with the [`JSENCODE()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) Visualforce function to ensure that the data under the user's control is merged safely as a literal JavaScript string.

Remember, Visualforce knows nothing about JavaScript syntax. If the value of that parameter includes a quote (`"`), it will terminate your string and potentially allow an attack to inject arbitrary JavaScript to execute in the context of your Visualforce page.